# The Windows Product Key Deleted After Uninstalling Norton (From Xfinity)?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, product-key

I have just uninstalled the free Norton antivirus package from Xfinity, and replaced it with McAfee Security Center from AT&T, due to changing internet providers.

When I restarted Windows 7 SP1, it appears that my windows product ID was somehow deleted, and I am getting a "This copy of Windows is not genuine" message on my desktop. Any suggestions about what caused this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Protip: Never, ever, ever use Norton or McAfee. Use [MSE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) instead. And for your issue, just try re-entering your key.

Comment: I tried reentering my key but it does not work anymore. This copy of windows was downloaded about a year ago from my school which offered free copies of Microsoft products to students (at one of each). I have used it with the product key until now with no issues. I have graduated since over six months so I don't think my product key suddenly lapsed since it was offered for after graduation also

Comment: Use the phone activation.  The license key is still valid unless you have activated it to many times, even if you have done so, explain the situation and they will help activate it.  Technically your suppose to stop using it, so avoid actually saying, your no longer a student. Unless blacklisted a Windows license NEVER expires

Comment: I will try phone activation. I am interested if anyone has an explanation of how the product key got deleted. I feel that it is somehow related to deleting Norton antivirus